# Estoy utilizando la tabla users que viene predefinida al crear un proyecto en laravel, pero al insertar usuario me da error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, login

Estoy intentando insertar un usuario (registrar) a la tabla users pero me da el sigueinte error:

Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'password' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)

No se que puede ser. El codigo en el controlador es el siguiente:

```
 public function register(Request $request){
        $user = new User();
        $user->name=$request->name;
        $user->email=$request->email;
        $user->name=Hash::make($request->password); //para guardar la contraseña cifrada

        $user->save();
        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect(route("privada"));
   }
```

Comment: estas llamando al Hash:make para setear el password, pero se lo seteas tambien al name (en lugar de al campo password)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error te esta indicando que el campo password necesita un valor. Al no indicar dicho valor, la bbdd intenta poner el valor por defecto de dicho campo, pero no esta definido. Esto suele ser porque no se ha indicado el valor en el campo (en este caso, en el objeto $user->password).

Entiendo que esto:

```
$user->name=Hash::make($request->password);
```

no es correcto, porque quieres setear el password.

El codigo deberia ser:

```
$user->password=Hash::make($request->password); <-- campo name a password
```

Comment: Si era eso,  gracias. Ya me estaba volviendo loca